# Riemannian manifold with almost nonnegative sectional curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, manifolds-with-boundary

A Riemannian manifold has almost nonnegative sectional curvature if it admits a sequence of  Riemannian metric $g_{i}$ such that $sec(g_{i})\geq (-1/i)$ and $D(g_{i})\leq 1$ where $sec(g_{i})$ is the sectional curvature of $g_{i}$ and $D(g_{i})$ is the diameter of $g_{i}$. ( see, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0001870820302759)

My questions are those:

1-Could this definition be true for manifold with boundary?

2- What is the definition of the Riemannian curvature of manifold with boundary?

I have not found any things in the literature review about that when the boundary exists.

Comment: An $n$-dimensional manifold with boundary still has an $n$-dimensional tangent space at boundary points. Of course, you can also talk about the tangent space of the boundary, which is a hyperplane. The Riemannian metric is still defined, as is the curvature tensor, at boundary points. As with submanifolds in general, you might look at the second fundamental form and the Codazzi equations at the boundary points.

Comment: I do not understand the question: You are free to make any definition you like as long as it is clearly written. What is stopping you from repeating the standard definition in the case of manifolds with boundary? Along the way, you are free to introduce whatever boundary conditions on the metric you find useful. Whatever you write, will be your definition. On the other hand, without some boundary conditions, this definition is unlikely to have any interesting topological consequences since every parallelizable connected manifold with boundary admits a flat metric.